# How to identify all rows in one table that are not in another table -- with a nuance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008.  I am using the following technique to identify all rows in one table `table_A` that are not in another table `table_B`:

```
SELECT
table_A.key
FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B
ON
table_A.key = table_B.key
WHERE
table_B.key IS NULL
```

I am actually identifying all rows in `table_A` that aren't in other tables, listed by different keys. For example,

```
SELECT
'col1|col2|col3' AS Columns_in_Question,
CASE WHEN table_B.colx IS NULL THEN 'col1 value not found' ELSE '' END + '|' +
CASE WHEN table_C.colphi IS NULL THEN 'col2 value not found' ELSE '' END + '|' +
CASE WHEN table_D.cola IS NULL THEN 'col3 value not found' ELSE '' END AS Error_Messages,
CASE WHEN table_B.colx IS NULL THEN table_A.col1 ELSE '' END + '|' +
CASE WHEN table_C.colphi IS NULL THEN table_A.col2 ELSE '' END + '|' +
CASE WHEN table_D.cola IS NULL THEN table_A.col3 ELSE '' END AS Offending_Values
FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B
ON
table_A.col1 = table_B.colx
LEFT JOIN table_C
ON
table_A.col2 = table_C.colphi
LEFT JOIN table_D
ON
table_A.col3 = table_D.cola
WHERE
table_B.colx IS NULL
OR
table_C.colphi IS NULL
OR
table_D.cola IS NULL
```

My issue is that I need to screen out `NULL` in the columns of `table_A`.  For example, suppose `table_A.col1` is `null` for a handful of rows.  These handful of rows will return (because of the `LEFT JOIN`).  But, because they're `NULL`, then they didn't really fail in the lookup against `table_B`.  So, I don't want them to return.  Normally, in the `WHERE` clause, I would just put something like

```
table_A.col1 IS NOT NULL
AND
table_B.colx IS NULL
```

In my actual situation, is it equivalent to just put this in a for each test?  For example, does the following achieve this?

```
WHERE
(table_B.colx IS NULL AND table_A.col1 IS NOT NULL)
OR
(table_C.colphi IS NULL AND table_A.col2 IS NOT NULL)
OR
(table_D.cola IS NULL AND table_A.col3 IS NOT NULL)
```

My concern is that I don't want to limit `table_A` to only those rows where all 3 columns are populated.  After all, even with just one of the columns populated, I need to still perform the test.

Or, is this a good way to screen out `NULLs` at all?

Comment: your normally used where should work.. just make sure you put the ORs in parenthesis `WHERE table_A.col1 IS NOT NULL AND (table_B.colx IS NULL OR table_C.colphi IS NULL OR table_D.cola IS NULL)`

Comment: Why not build it into the case statements instead?  E.g. `case when tableB.colx is NULL and tableA.col1 is not NULL then...`

Comment: I will be updating my CASE statements (as you suggested).  But, that is just for display.  I will still have the same problem if I don't alter my WHERE clause.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with `WHERE NOT EXISTS` instead of Left Joins where the right table value is null.  I don't think that there is any performance benefit, as the query optimizer will probably evaluate both as the same, but it will make the query more readable.  i.e. it becomes *obvious* that the intent is to find rows that don't have a matching row.